# Converting RSSTV XML with XSLT

Tags: xslt, rss

I am trying to transform [RSSTV](http://www.rss-tv.org/) XML using XSLT.
The problem I am having is that I need the XML to look like this:
`<?xml version="1.0"?><rss xmlns:tv="http://www.rss-tv.org/rss/tv1.0" version="2.0"><channel>`

However, I am unable to create the rss element with this attribute.
I tried using `<xsl:attribute>` but failed to achieve it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted an example of an RSS item, so that we can see what you are trying to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just write**:

```
<rss xmlns:tv="http://www.rss-tv.org/rss/tv1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel/>
</rss>
```

`xmlns:tv="http://www.rss-tv.org/rss/tv1.0"` isn't an attribute -- it is a *namespace definition* and defines a namespace node belonging to the `rss` element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what your problem is :

Here are two ways to do it.

1) Assuming namespace is hardcoded in your xslt.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
            <rss xmlns:tv="http://www.rss-tv.org/rss/tv1.0" version="2.0"></rss>
</xsl:template>
```

2) Assuming you get the namespace from some other parameter :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="namespace">http://www.rss-tv.org/rss/tv1.0</xsl:variable>
        <rss xmlns:tv="{$namespace}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Create an element with your desired result.

Comment: but i need to nest some elements in the RSS element

Comment: @Himberjack this is just an example for your question only to depict that you can assign the whatever attribute you want to your rss element. Inside the tags you can put whatever other elements you want. With your abstract input this is what I could come up with..